# REGEX Replace Google sheets Replace multiple numbers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this formula in REGEX Google Sheets:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(P74, "\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)T(L)E OF|(T)A(B)LET|(C)APLE(T)|(CAP)SULE|(AMP)OULE|(S)ACHE(T)|(A)P(P)(L)ICATOR(B)OT(T)(L)E OF|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L)|3.5 MG|(ALUMINIUM/ALUMINIUM)|[()]|@|OF)", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10")
```

And i have this data in many rows:

```
BX-5VL @ 6 ML
BX-5VL @ 8 ML
BX-5VL @ 15 ML
```

I would like to simply remove all numbers for and ML attached to return like this:

```
BX-5VL 
BX-5VL 
BX-5VL
```

Answer (score 1):

You may replace the following regex pattern with empty string:

```
\s*@\s+\d+\s+ML$
```

Sample code:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(
     REGEXREPLACE(P74, "your current regex", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10"),
     "\s*@\s+\d+\s+ML$",
     ""
)
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your help i dont get it how i can put that command twice in the formula : =REGEXREPLACE(P2, "\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)T(L)E OF|"\s*@\s+\d+\s+ML$", ""|(T)A(B)LET|(C)APLE(T)|(CAP)SULE|(AMP)OULE|(S)ACHE(T)|(A)P(P)(L)ICATOR|(SUP)POSITORY|(B)OT(T)(L)E OF|(E)(F)FERVESCENT|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L)|3.5 MG|(ALUMINIUM/ALUMINIUM)|[()]|@|OF)", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10")

Comment: Oh...didn't know you wanted this as part of your original formula.  The easiest thing to do here might be to just wrap your current formula.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to have a single regex for all requirements, and sometimes it is ugly.  I'm leaning towards the latter in this case.

Comment: still dont work for some reason : =REGEXREPLACE(
     REGEXREPLACE(P2, "\s*(\d*)\s*(?:(B)O(T)T(L)E OF|(T)A(B)LET|(C)APLE(T)|(CAP)SULE|(AMP)OULE|(S)ACHE(T)|(A)P(P)(L)ICATOR|(SUP)POSITORY|(B)OT(T)(L)E OF|(E)(F)FERVESCENT|(BL)ISTER|(V)IA(L)|3.5 MG|(ALUMINIUM/ALUMINIUM)|[()]|@|OF)", "$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10"),
     "\s*@\s+\d+\s+ML$",
     ""
)

Comment: You may also try: `REGEXREPLACE(P74, "^(.*)\s*@\s+\d+\s+ML$", "$1")` ... I don't know the quirks of this API, the current regex works in the demo and should also be working here.

Answer (score 1):

all you need:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, "@")),,1)
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "@? \d+ ML$", )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Yes it works thanks, but i have to replace so many things like in my formula. I will have to create many columns

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
function removeAccents() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("F3:F");
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/á|à|ã|ä}/g, 'a');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/é|ë|ê/g, 'e');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/í|ì|î/g, 'i');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/ó|ò|õ|ô/g, 'o');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/ú|ù|û/g, 'u');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/ç/g, 'c');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/[|]|\/|\\|\|/g, '-');
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
};
```